# Cant install Eclipse. Log is as follows

Tags: eclipse, installation, ide

Can't install eclipse. Log is below.

I have already tried: Restarting, Installing JRE8, redownloading installer, fluching cache(Eclipse cache, AppData), disabled antivirus and firewall.

```
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_151-b12
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.oxygen
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.8.0.v20170408-0745, build=3059, branch=2161405b80cf99ed791602ba56cdf44084f5ca43
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.8.0.v20170531-0903, build=3059, branch=2161405b80cf99ed791602ba56cdf44084f5ca43
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.8.0.v20170318-0419, build=3059, branch=2161405b80cf99ed791602ba56cdf44084f5ca43
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Oxygen))
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Offline = false
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Mirrors = true
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Resolving 25 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\JamesFrench\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement epp.package.java [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
[2017-12-21 15:41:43] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2017-12-21 15:41:46] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201712201001.
org.tukaani.xz.XZFormatException: Input is not in the XZ format
  at org.tukaani.xz.common.DecoderUtil.decodeStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.initialize(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:80)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

[2017-12-21 15:41:46]
```

Log has been included in entirety.

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518849#c5

Comment: Do you have access to a virtual machine or another computer to try on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete all the files which are already on the system in users folder related to eclipse.

Delete workspace if any. (Save projects seperately)

Try installing the eclipse from the official site. Try not to go for the online installers. Install full software

The Software installation will be succesful

Comment: I have tried this already, can you send me a link to the download you advise me to use and I will try it again. Thank you.

Comment: RROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen.
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201712201001.
org.tukaani.xz.XZFormatException: Input is not in the XZ format

Comment: Try to delete contents of "~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache" and "~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache"

Comment: Deleted first entery second entery doesnt exist. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try the eclipse support forums instead. It looks like this may have to do with **firewall / proxy issues**:

- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1086342&goto=1763986&

Did you download the installer from here? http://download.eclipse.org/

**UPDATE**: I just did a test install myself, and it failed with a different error message from yours. The install worked after I just changed the installation path (i added "2" at the end of the existing path).

Comment: Looked at the post im affraid it is one I have already looked at. Also added 2 to the path no difference. Finally yes I did download the installer from there.

Comment: @Frenchie Are you behind a firewall / proxy?

Comment: I am usually behind a firewall however I disabled this when trying to install.

Comment: If that is a software firewall, I guess you could also be behind a hardware firewall and / or a proxy. Are there any proxy settings in IE? ``Tools => Internet Options => Connections => LAN settings`` (or equivalent in your language version of IE).